# Open the menu with Hover and close it by clicking outside the cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My problem is that by moving the shopping cart button, the card menu opens and by clicking except the card menu, the card box should be closed. I wrote some of these, help me get the solution, thank you.

[image: image project]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.shop').hover(function() {
    $('.carts').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
});
```

Comment: hey, i got answer repost the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the clicked target (`e.target`) is not the `.carts` element (negation with `!`):

```js
if (!$(e.target).is('.carts')) {
  $('.carts').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.shop').hover(function () {
    $('.carts').css('visibility', 'visible');
  });

  $('body').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.carts')) {
      $('.carts').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.shop {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.carts {
  background-color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="shop">Shop</span>
<div class="carts">Test</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's right, but clicking on the cart will also remove it

Comment: i changed it to checking the `e.target`

Comment: If I want this event to be clicked, how is it done? Because I replaced the float with one click, but the code did not work randomly. Solution + Tell me the reason for this failure. Grateful

Comment: To answer this i need at least the html for that (just the necessary part). Edit your question and past it. Furthermore i need to know what you mean with `event to be clicked` because an event can't be clicked -  the `click` is an event...

Comment: .cart
                            a(href="javascript:void(0)").shop
                                i.fi-rs-shopping-cart-check 
                                span.badge_shop.badge 16

                            figure.carts.d-none.d-lg-block 
                                .header
                                    a.status(href="javascript:void(0)") 
                                        p.cart_title  سبد خرید 
                                        p.balance 25 کالا

Comment: This is no HTML and is not added to your question...

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $(".carts").hide();
});

$(".carts").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carts" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;border: 1px solid;"></div>
```